Who are the divergence free vector fields of a compact Lie group?
Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $X\in\mathfrak{X}(G)$ a divergence free vector field. Is there a characterization of such fields?
For example, if $G=S^1$, from the fact that it is parallelizable and 1-dimensional, the divergence free vector fields are the constant ones.

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but for a left-invariant frame $(E_i)$ we can write any vector field $X \in \mathfrak X(G)$ as $X = X^i E_i$, in which case the incompressibility (divergence-freeness) condition is just $E_i \cdot X^i = 0$ (with the Einstein summation convention in effect). If $\dim G = 1$, the sum has just $1$ term, $E_1 \cdot X^1 = 0$, which says that $X^1$, hence $X$, is left invariant.

For $\dim G > 1$, all left-invariant vector fields are incompressible, but a general incompressible vector field will depend locally on $\dim G - 1$ functions of $\dim G$ variables.
